# Can two different sets of capabilities be set to one file?

Tags: linux, posix, capabilities

I'd like to set different capabilities to permitted and inherited sets of my file. Something like this:

```
sudo setcap cap_fsetid=ei mybinary
sudo setcap cap_kill=ep mybinary
```

However, the latter command overrides the former one. Is it even possible to can manage capabilities this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getcap` to get the list of currently set capabilities. Since these are whitespace separated you can add more like this:

```bsh
sudo setcap first_capability=itsvalue executable_fname
sudo setcap "$(getcap executable_fname) newcap=value" executable_fname
```

(the capability list being whitespace separated: as cited in `man setcap`, that's described in `man cap_from_text`)

Caveat: querying before setting is *not* safe from race conditions – make sure no other process is concurrently setting capabilities.

If you know all capabilities at any given point in time, it's easier:

```bsh
sudo setcap "first_capability=itsvalue newcap=value" executable_fname
```

In this context, `+` and `=` can be used to raise the capabilities. Using `=` here is easier to read, but there are some corner cases where `+` builds up state more predictably. Specifically where the listed capabilities for two different assignments have a common subset. For example these two are not equivalent:

```bsh
$ sudo setcap "first=i second=p first,second=e" executable
$ sudo setcap "first=i second=p first,second+e" executable
```

The 2nd of them is equivalent to:

```bsh
$ sudo setcap "first=ie second=pe" executable
```

Comment: `=` can only be used once in such a string. If you use it twice, the second one will override the first.

Comment: @Tinkerer, why is it so? I've tried to perform "sudo setcap "cap_fsetid=ei cap_kill=ep" mybinary" and getcap returns exactly what I expected "mybinary = cap_fsetid+ei cap_kill+ep". And your suggestion (sudo setcap "cap_fsetid=ei cap_kill+ep" mybinary) works the same way.

Comment: I'm going by the documentation which says `=` resets the state. But now that you mention it, I see that's only true of the listed capabilities on the left of the `=`. So, since the two entries are non-overlapping, it does as you say! Learned something. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to up vote again but I need you to edit in some way to unlock my downvote... Perhaps mention `+` as another method?

Comment: I've added some discussion. If that's approved, I'll be able to change my vote.